# PHPStorm ignores Xdebug request from Guzzle

Tags: apache, phpstorm, xdebug, guzzle

I've set up Guzzle to include the Xdebug cookie when it makes a request to my API. I've added the following line to my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` to watch the cookie's as requests come through:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Cookie}i\"" common
```

If I make a request with this cookie through the Chrome REST console, xdebug hits a breakpoint. The request in the access logs is:

```
192.168.50.1 - - [17/Mar/2015:15:47:36 +0000] "GET /app_dev.php/user?id=1&authuserid=1 HTTP/1.1" 301 569 "XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM"
```

When Guzzle makes the very same request, the breakpoint is not hit.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Mar/2015:15:42:17 +0000] "GET /app_dev.php/user?id=1 HTTP/1.1" 301 501 "XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM"
```

Obviously we are missing `authuserid` as a GET parameter, but this shouldnt effect xdebug. If this is being set as a hidden cookie by Guzzle maybe thats where I need to set the xdebug session?

I've had this working in the past before, but Im completely lost with this now.

Comment: Have you tried with GET parameter instead of cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My xdebug config (`/etc/php.d/15-xdebug.ini` or ) was:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so"
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.50.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="<AMP home\tmp>"
```

Reducing my config to:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.50.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_enable=1
```

Allowed my API to connect to xdebug.

Through process of elimination, at least one of the culprits was:

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

> **xdebug.remote_connect_back** 
> Type: boolean, Default value: 0, Introduced in Xdebug > 2.1 If enabled, the xdebug.remote_host setting
>   is ignored and Xdebug will try to connect to the client that made the
>   HTTP request. It checks the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] variable to find
>   out which IP address to use. Please note that there is no filter
>   available, and anybody who can connect to the webserver will then be
>   able to start a debugging session, even if their address does not
>   match xdebug.remote_host.

Although I still dont understand why this effected the functionality of xdebug in this case, as both the app and API were both on my virtual machine.

Comment: From your logs: `192.168.50.1` (your physical machine IP, where PhpStorm is running -- as seen from VM) vs `127.0.0.1` (your local VM). **P.S.** You should have mentioned that it's an remote debug / running on VM. For local it would have made no difference but for remote...